# How do I display an image using the Dynamic Background module?

Tags: 7, panels

I have been struggling to get the [Dynamic Background](https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_background) module working for users' profiles. The profiles are displayed in a panel.

I enabled the Panel and User sub-module and after hours of trial and error I found a CSS combination that seems to work: #page #main-wrapper.

So the image displays as a background. But if I go to `/user/[uid]/backgrounds` to enable a background image for that user, it works but the image displays for ALL users, even when the other users have not enabled a background image.

I am at a loss because I thought that everything after `user/[uid]` only affected that user.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Update: There's got to be something wrong with the module. When I uncheck the image, it still displays. The only way to stop displaying it is by deleting it.

Comment: Hm, could that be because of a "clear cache"-required situation? Otherwise I wouldn't know where such (deleted) image could still come from, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also completed the required **configuration** steps as described in the [Readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/dynamic_background/tree/README.txt#n68) of this module. I.e.:

> Enable the modules/extensions that you want to use and go to the administration interface at /admin/config/user-interface/backgrounds/settings. Start by filling out the form and remember to fill out the CSS behaviour section. Then go into the configuration tab for each module/extension that you have enabled and as a minimum filling out the CSS behaviour fields.
>
> Go to /admin/config/user-interface/backgrounds and select some images to upload after pressing "Save configuration" the form will change and allow you to select a default image. If you have enabled some of the extensions go to their location and select one of the uploaded images. See the extension descriptions above for information on where to select images for each extension.

Comment: Yes, I have done all that. You seem confident that it is a good module. So, I will try again, maybe using a different version. One of the problems is that there is no decent documentation other than the readme.txt file and it is a guessing game just to determine how the sub modules are supposed to behave. I will report back. Thank you. :)